# Suggestions on documentation of a DB model when using Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, documentation-generation

Any experiences on how to document Entity Framework 4 based Database projects?

There is the Document and Summary properties on the Entities, but if we want to regenerate the model from the database at some point, it will be lost!

Is there some way to map documentation data inside SQL to the Entities in the EDMX file so it is safe.

Suggestions of other best practices? Ideally I want to be able to augo generate html/helpfile documentation from the DB when we deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement that CSDL (part of EDMX) changes will be lost if you regenerate is incorrect. This is not LINQ to SQL. CSDL changes are retained during an update.